# Gradle remove specific dependency configuration from generated pom

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, maven-publish

I need to ignore some dependencies defined in the configuration "configurations.nonDistributable" when using gradles plugin maven-publish to generate pom files, I haven't found a reliable way of doing this, except for manually parsing the XML to remove them. Am I missing something, does gradle allow for an easier way of doing this?

build.gradle example:

```
configurations{
    nonDistributable
}

dependencies {
    nonDistributable ('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.52.0'){
        exclude group:'com.google.guava' // included in elasticsearch
    }

    nonDistributable ('com.assertthat:selenium-shutterbug:0.3') {
        transitive = false
    }

    nonDistributable 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40'
    nonDistributable fileTree(dir: 'non-distributable-libs', include: '*.jar')
}

// generate subprojects pom
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    model {
        tasks.generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication {
            destination = file("$buildDir/../../$distDir/build/pom/$project.name-pom.xml")
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        publishing {
            publications {
                mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                    from components.java
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// generate root project pom
model {
    tasks.generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication {
        destination = file("$buildDir/../$distDir/build/pom/$project.name-pom.xml")
    }
}
afterEvaluate { project ->
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own publication pom. It would look something like this:

```
customMaven(MavenPublication) {
    artifactId 'myArtifactId'
    pom.withXml {
        def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
        configurations.specialConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
            def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
            dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
            dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
            dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create a special configuration that extends from only those configurations that you want to include.

I am using this to create a special pom that contains all testRuntime dependencies to be used for integration tests separated from the main project.